# Can't start npm via wmic

Tags: windows, batch-file, npm, wmic

If i place into bat-file command to start `node`

```
wmic process call create "npm run go","%~dp0."
```

everything works fine:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>wmic process call create "node go","D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm\."
Идет выполнение (Win32_Process)->Create()
Метод успешно вызван.
Параметры вывода:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 13292;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

But if I use `npm` instead

```
wmic process call create "npm run go","%~dp0."
```

error 9 occurs, which [according to msdn msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) means that path is not found:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>wmic process call create "npm run go","D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm\."
Идет выполнение (Win32_Process)->Create()
Метод успешно вызван.
Параметры вывода:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 9;
};
```

File `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "wmic-npm-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "go": "node go"
  }
}
```

File `go.js`:

```
setInterval(function () {
  console.log(require('process').cwd());
}, 1000);
```

If simply start `npm` from console, everything works:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>npm run go

> wmic-npm-test@0.0.0 go D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
> node go

D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
```

I'm starting it via `wmic` [to get process id](//stackoverflow.com/q/46182585/4928642).

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717840/178988)

Comment: this is because npm is a cmd file but not executable and probably wmic does not uses file associations.As npm is in the %path% this can be easy worked around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There file `npm.cmd` and `npm` file for `sh`:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

To execute `npm` command you need to specify that you want to run cmd-file:

```
wmic process call create "npm.cmd run go","%~dp0."
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this (mode details in my comment under the question):

```
@echo off

for %%a in (npm.cmd) do set "npm_path=%%~f$PATH:a"
echo %npm_path%

wmic process call create "cmd.exe /c call \"%npm_path%\" ","%~dp0."
```

Comment: Thank you! But a solution is much simpler this time :)